# SSRS 2008 R2 Filter Tablix Group But Use All Data in Group for Aggregation

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am building an SSRS 2008 R2 report with a SharePoint list as the dataset (can't use a database...but not sure it would help here anyway).

Here is a sample of the data I have (only relevant fields shown).

```
Workstream     Title   Show_On_Workstream_Report    Value
----------     ------  -------------------------    ------
W-A            T-A     True                         1
W-A            T-B     False                        2
W-A            T-C     False                        3
W-B            T-D     True                         1
W-B            T-E     True                         2
W-B            T-F     False                        2
W-C            T-G     False                        1
W-C            T-H     False                        2
W-C            T-I     False                        2
```

I need my tablix output to be the following.

```
Workstream/Title     Max_Value
----------------     ---------
W-A                  3
  T-A                1
W-B                  2
  T-D                1
  T-E                2

*note that W-C is NOT shown in the tablix output since no entries have Show_On_Workstream_Report set to true.
*This I believe is where the kicker is in this problem...
```

I got the Tablix format down in regards to grouping and whatnot but can't quite figure out how to both include all records for the workstream in the Max_value calculation but only show the "selected" titles under the workstream.

Items that I believe would need to be filled in.

```
Row Groups
  Workstream
     Filters: ?
  Title
     Filters: Show_On_Workstream_Report = True
```

I am open to custom report code if you think it would solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 row groups, WorkStream, and its child Title (the details line)?
Add a total before the Title line, set it to pick the max from Workstream group. The workstream group should not have the filter applied

```
 =Max(Fields!VALUE.Value, "Workstream")
```